# Finishing an activity from another class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, stack

I am working on an app that requires a permanent internet connection. If no internet connection is present I want the user to be logged out of the app (taken to the login screen).
I have a network receiver class that detects network connectivity. I want this class to either terminate the activity on top of the stack OR to start a new login activity and delete the entire history stack.

The problem is that I can't finish the foreground activity from inside the my receiver class, and there is no way of knowing which activity the user is in when there is a network fail. And if I'm starting a new login activity from this class, when the user presses "back" he is taken back to the app(if he reconnects to a network), but the app is not logged in and crashes.

Tried using `myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK || FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` when starting a new login activity from my NetworkStateReceiver class. But it doesn't work, to my understanding this creates a new task in which the only activity is the one I started (login), but the old task with all the other activities remain intact.

So I need :

*-either a way to finish a foreground activity from a class*

*-or a way to start a new activity from a class and emptying the activity stack*

Here's the receiver code for what it's worth:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//     super.onReceive(context, intent);
 Log.d("app","Network connectivity change");
 if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
     Login.apiKey = null;
    NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        Log.i("app","Network "+ni.getTypeName()+" connected");
    }
 }
 if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE) && !Login.loginActive) {
        Log.d("app","There's no network connectivity");

        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection. Logging out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //logout
        Receiver.engine(context).halt();
        Receiver.mSipdroidEngine = null;
        Receiver.reRegister(0);
        new Thread(ChatList.runnable).interrupt();
        ChatList.buddyList.clear();
        Login.apiKey = null;
        Log.i("Logout", "Logged out!");
        Login.loggedOut = true;


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//          myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);



     }
   }
}
```

**SOLUTION:** 
Passed reference from all activities to receiver

```
//random user_activity
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    NetworkStateReceiver.curActivity = null;
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NetworkStateReceiver.curActivity = user_activity.this; //edited : getParent() doesn't always work
}
```

and in network receiver in `onReceive()` :

```
            if(curActivity != null)
        {
            curActivity.finish();
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pass the receiver a reference to the current activity(say, in `onResume`?). Make sure to null it in `onPause`, though, or you're looking at some ugly memory leaks. Then, in `onReceive`, you can `curActivity.finish()`(or do nothing if it's null) before you start the login activity.

Comment: You sir, are brilliant!! I passed a reference from the current activity to the receiver and it worked! Thanks!